# Prevent child A override method 1 but not for child B

Tags: c#

I have class A is super class, class B and C inherits A. Class A have method

```
public virtual GetName() {}
```

I want B can not override that method but C can do.

How can I do it?

PS: I got interview and they said they can do it but they didn't tell me how do that.

Comment: Were there any other details in their question? As written, it appears they were incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, the interview question was wrong: you can't (via simple, non-reflection means, at least) allow `C` to override that without allowing `B` to override it.

If `C` were in the same assembly as `A`, while `B` were in a separate one, you could create these rules by using an `internal` method:

```
public class A
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return GetNameInternal();
    }
    internal virtual string GetNameInternal()
    {
        return "A";
    }
}
public class C : A
{
    internal override string GetNameInternal()
    {
        return "C";
    }
}
// in other assembly
public class B : A
{
    // invalid due to scope:
    //internal override string GetNameInternal() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible in this scenario. The polymorphism (class inheritance) implies that the super class has no knowledge of who inherits itself, so your superclass cannot say "The `ClassB` cannot override this method but `ClassC` could" since it doesn't know their existence.

Maybe you misunderstood the question?

Comment: thanks for your comment, I think I don't misunderstood, he said he can do it. I think the design pattern is the edge of this. Is it possible?

Comment: Look at Tim's answer, it is indeed a way to do it